# Review audit failed

Tags: support, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I was reviewing some posts and this came up: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4500300:

> class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration def change create_table :comments do |t| t.integer :post_id t.text :body
>
> ```
>   t.timestamps
> end
> ```
>
> end end
>
> C:\Users\MEGHA\bbbb>rake db:migrate rake aborted! SyntaxError: C:/Users/MEGHA/bbbb/db/migrate/20140402130040_create_comments.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end C:65535:in `disable_ddl_transaction' Tasks: TOP => db:migrate (See full trace by running task with --trace)

I saw that it was of low quality and it needed some work so I clicked edit. It said that the post had been deleted so I clicked "no action needed" because no action was needed if it had been deleted.

I have now been banned from editing for a whole month.

Comment: How would you have edited that post to anything useful? :)

Comment: You obviously weren't banned for failing 1 audit.  To trigger a month, you'd either need to have a number of recent review bans or a mod would have had to manually ban you - which wouldn't only be because of 1 failed audit

Comment: Well, if OP failed the review because they clicked Edit, and the system said "This question is so awful that editing isn't appropriate, you fail", that would be a good observation.

Comment: "You take whatever action you would have if the post weren't deleted." -- some answer I can't remember

Comment: @juergend I would of reformatted it and made it abit more useful.

Comment: I doubt that post has any value. Instead of answering it seems to be another error log dump.

Comment: this particular audit item is quite slippery. And audit design is not optimal: Edit -> "post was deleted" -> what next? But monthly review ban suggests that you have failed some audits before, this was not the first time was it?

Comment: @gnat I did some time ago when I was new to reviewing posts and I was a bit too generous with some of them.

Comment: you were too generous this time as well. But the test item and design of the audit flow are really slippery

Comment: @gnat what do i do now.

Comment: Enjoy not editing for a month. You can make an effective contribution answering questions which, looking at your profile, you do well.

Comment: take a break from reviewing for a month, spend it pondering on how you could do better next time. Trust me, I've been suspended once a while ago (from suggesting edits) - if you give it a bit more thought on how to do better, this will turn out time well spent

Comment: @gnat Thanks. I was only two reviews of a silver review badge :-(

Comment: @Bathsheba OP failed first post audit, not that of suggested edits (agree that those for suggested edits are really hard to fail)

Comment: I might also point out that this wasn't a particularly good review: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4471676 . The system banned you for 30 days because you had been previously banned for 7 days after failing this audit: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4365462 and for 2 days before that for failing a few other audits. We do need people to pay close attention in the First Posts and Late Answers queues, because bad reviews there can let non-answers and spam slip onto the site.

Comment: This is a bug, @gnat - see link. Edit was still not the right choice here though.

Comment: thanks @Shog9 - it makes perfect sense now! Agree wrt edit being wrong way for passing - clicking the link should fail the audit

Comment: My fail is other, I want to comment some "high quality" post, why it's wrong?

Answer (score 10):

**"I saw that it was of low quality and it needed some work..."**

This is nothing more than a log dump.  There was nothing to edit, it should have been deleted.  So, that was a strike against you.

**"@gnat I did some time ago when I was new to reviewing posts and I was a bit too generous with some of them."**

This explains the month ban.

**"@gnat Thanks. I was only two reviews of a silver review badge :-("**

And so does this.  This isn't a game.  SO doesn't need monkeys pressing buttons.  SO needs people who are going to put a full effort into making this site better.  And that means reading every review question carefully and making the right choices about whether a question or answer can be improved, or whether it just needs to be deleted.  Take the month to think about what you really want from SO and what you want to give back.  Those 2 answers should align with their [desired functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/about).